# How do you temporarily disable a linkbutton while a dropdownlist post back is occurring in ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a dropdownlist with two options and a link button to submit the selected option. By default, the first option is selected. When a different option is selected, it takes a few seconds to do the OnSelectedIndexChanged event. The problem I am facing is that when the user makes a selection and it is still processing the event, they can also click the button that is supposed to send the selection. What I would like to do is only disable the button when an event (OnSelectedIndexChanged) is occurring, but not be disabled by default.

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <fieldset>
            <div class="AlignRight">
                <asp:Label ID="ddlLabelEncoding" runat="server" CssClass="rtText" Text="Select Export Encoding:" AssociatedControlID="dd_encodingType"></asp:Label>
                <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="dd_encodingType" CssClass="csStyle FormPulldownSmall" AutoPostBack="true">
                    <asp:ListItem Selected="True" Text="UTF-8 (Default)" value="1"></asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Text="UTF-16LE" value="2"></asp:ListItem>
                </asp:DropDownList>
            </div>
        </fieldset>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>

<div class="AlignRight"><asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="lb_ExportTxt" Text="Save Selection" CssClass="TextLink"></asp:LinkButton></div>
```

When the index of the dropdownlist has changed, it sets the view state:

```
protected void dd_EncodingType_OnSelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ViewState["encodingType"] = dd_encodingType.SelectedValue;
}
```

By default, UTF-8 is selected so I want the button to be enabled when the form loads just in case the user doesn't need to select a different value. But if they do and the event is processing, it needs to be disabled.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I actually think it better to "hide" the link button while the processing occurs. However, if you hide linkbutton, and any content is to the right, or often below, then it will "move up", and that can be a bit jerkey.

Link buttons are easy to hide, but "harder" to disable, since they have a "hyper-link" in them.

but, since a post-back is occuring, then we can blow torch the linkbutton, and when the server side event is done, then the control will be re-biult and re-rendered, so it don't matter.

Say this markup for dropdown list (even in repeater).

```
                <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server"
                    AutoPostBack="true"
                    OnSelectedIndexChanged="DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged"
                    onchange="mydisable()"
                    >
                    <asp:ListItem>Yes</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>No</asp:ListItem>
                </asp:DropDownList>
```

And then right after repeater we have this:

```
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>

        <br />

        <div class="AlignRight">
            <asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="lb_ExportTxt" 
                Text="Save Selection" CssClass="TextLink"></asp:LinkButton>

        </div>

        <script>
            function mydisable() {
                var lBut = $('#<%= lb_ExportTxt.ClientID %>')
                //href = $('[id$=Lnk_Orgnz]').attr('href');
                lBut.removeAttr('href');
                lBut.attr('disabled', 'disabled');
            }
        </script>
```

So, we get the link button. We remove href, we then disable.

Somewhat of a issue, the disabled of a link button tends to not change the look + feel of the linkbutton, so that's what I suggested a possible consider is to hide the linkbutton (but, depending on the rest of the markup, it hard to tell if that will not jump things around).

So, use above, but consider using .hide(). then the js code becomes this:

```
        <script>
            function mydisable() {
                var lbut = $('#<%= lb_ExportTxt.ClientID %>')
                lbut.hide()
            }
        </script>
```